#  Modules to extend the Display Suite module?

Tags: display-suite

Just that. I find the Display Suite module really useful for my projects.

Are there more modules to extend its functionality in any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like the combination of Display suite with Custom Formatters - http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters & with the Omega Theme, with these tools you can almost entirely skip having to use tpl.php files to theme your site's layout and content.

Also listed on the Display suite page you have Field Group - http://drupal.org/project/field_group & Rendable elemenets - http://drupal.org/project/rel However Rendable elements doesn't seem to work that well quite yet but it looks promising.

Comment: I didn´t know of custom formatters. Do you know of any video/screencast which shows me how to use it? I tried http://drupal.org/project/rel , it looks really useful but is not ready for production yet.

Comment: This was pretty helpful http://bxl2011.drupaldays.org/node/303